# as3 change font size as stage size changes

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

As it reads I want to change the font size as the stage size changes.

I have private var myFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();

And then when the object gets made it writes the following

```
        _buttonText.wordWrap = true;

        myFormat.size = 15;
        myFormat.align = TextFormatAlign.CENTER;
        _buttonText.textColor = 0x222428;
        myFormat.bold = 'true';
        _buttonText.defaultTextFormat = myFormat;       
        _buttonText.text = text;
```

Then in my on enter frame I want to resize the text, I have tried a couple things but nothing seems to work, currently it looks like this.

```
      myFormat.size = stage.stageWidth / 136.53;
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A TextFormat object has no effect unless applied to a TextField. Besides if the font size should be linked to the stage size then a factor size of some kind should be applied as well. At the end it looks like this:

```
myFormat.size = 15 * fontSizeFactor;
//_buttonText.defaultTextFormat = myFormat;this is irrelevant if size should be dynamic.
//instead text should be set then TextFormat should be set again.
_buttonText.text = text;   
_buttonText.setTextFormat(myFormat);//this is dynamic
```

now on enter frame:

```
myFormat.size = 15 * fontSizeFactor;
_buttonText.setTextFormat(myFormat);//apply the format again or else nothing will happen
```

Comment: Thanks that really helped, now when the button where the text lives moves the text is not staying inside the button, any idea how to fix that problem?

I tried
    sp.removechild
    sp.addchild

But it never helped the problem

Comment: The TextField grows or shrink depending on the font size and it can even move depending on TextFieldAutoSize property. You have to reset its position by code according to its changing size.

Comment: I have written 

_buttonText.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;

However if the button moves left and becomes smaller the text ends up outside the button. 

Atleast the font size is now changing though